# Sitemap for a member based website

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I would like to have something cleared up.

On a member based website, there are certain pages that can only be accessed by a particular member; such as edit profile, edit password..etc.

My question is, do those pages need to be included in the sitemap that is submitted to search engines?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: do you want google to publicly list the private pages that should only be accessible by members? can google even crawl the private pages if they are not a member of your site?

Comment: Nope they can't crawl those pages if they are not a member. So I guess I won't include them in the sitemap.

Comment: Asking how a search engine will display/rank/parse your site is off topic. It might be more suitable on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Only add pages that you want search engines to index *and* are available to the search engine to be crawled. These pages do not meet either criteria.